# What would be the regex for this value? C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get the regex for this value:

`<5fond[3.4,550],[5.4,6.4,7.4, 8.4, 32.4],[ 9.4, 239.8662]`

The numbers (minus the second one which appears to just be an integer) can be any decimal value.

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

`private static readonly Regex RegexExp = new Regex(@"<5fond\[[0-9]*\.[0-9]+,[0-9]*\.[0-9]+],\[[0-9]*\.[0-9]+,[0-9]*\.[0-9]+,[0-9]*\.[0-9]+,[0-9]*\.[0-9]+\],\[[0-9]*\.[0-9]+,[0-9]*\.[0-9]+\]", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);`

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You miss `,\s*[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+` in the second bracket and you need to support integer values like `550` and use `\s*` to match any zero or more whitespaces.

Comment: Regex might not be the right tool for this job. In addition to the example you've given, what is the format of your inputs?

Comment: I would chuck your string in here: https://regex101.com/ and keep fiddling with it.  Just start left to right and you'll get there

Comment: @gunr2171 format is <5fond[decimal, integer],[decimal, decimal, decimal, decimal],[ decimal, decimal]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
<5fond\[\s*\d*\.?\d+(?:,\s*\d*\.?\d+)*\s*](?:,\s*\[\s*\d*\.?\d+(?:,\s*\d*\.?\d+)*\s*])*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QgCgB6/2). *Details*:

- `<5fond\[` - a `<5fond[` string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\d*\.?\d+` - an int/float number pattern
- `(?:,\s*\d*\.?\d+)*` - zero or more sequences of a comma, zero or more whitespaces, an int/float number
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `]` - a `]` char
- `(?:,\s*\[\s*\d*\.?\d+(?:,\s*\d*\.?\d+)*])*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `,` - a comma
  - `\s*\[\s*` - a `[` char enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
  - `\d*\.?\d+(?:,\s*\d*\.?\d+)*` - an int/float and then zero or more occurrences of a comma, zero or more whitespaces, an int/float number
  - `]` - a `]` char.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. Curious, for the second set of brackets where I have 5 floats, how would I be able to use regex to differentiate between 4 floats supplied and 5 floats surprised?

Comment: @bob123123123123 I can only answer this question if you provide exact expected result. For the time being, the solution accepts any amount of 1 or more comma-separated numbers inside any one or more square brackets.

Comment: So `<5fond[3.4,550],[5.4,6.4,7.4, 8.4],[ 9.4, 239.8662]` versus `<5fond[3.4,550],[5.4,6.4,7.4, 8.4, 32.4],[ 9.4, 239.8662]` for instance. How would you compare that you have the first option and not the second for instance :)?

Comment: @bob123123123123 You'd need to unroll the pattern, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/QgCgB6/3).